# How to access the Video files, which are present in iOS Files App using AVPlayer in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am trying to access the access the video files which are present in the iOS Files App. Trying to play videos using AVPlayer

I am able to access the videos but after some time when I try to access the same video I am getting the error from the AVPlayer.

```
let filemgr = FileManager.default
let docsDirURL = try! filemgr.url(for: .documentDirectory, 
  in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

let lastComp = docsDirURL.lastPathComponent
let pathy = "\(docsDirURL)"

if let urls = lap.videoURLs {
  self.lap = lap
  for url in urls {
    let urlComps = "\(url)".components(separatedBy: "/")
    var urlpath = ""
    for (index, element) in urlComps.enumerated() {
      if index > 9{
        urlpath +=  element + "/"
      }
    }

    print(urlpath)
    var pathz = pathy.replacingOccurrences(of: lastComp, with: urlpath)
    pathz = String(pathz.dropLast(2))
    print(pathz)

    let finalURL = NSURL(string: pathz)
//  let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: finalURL! as URL)
    playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .new, 
      context: &itemStatusContext)
    self.playerItems.append(playerItem)

    if self.queuePlayer == nil {
      self.queuePlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to play videos normally as before but I can only access it for some time like one minute and then after I received an error.

> Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSUnderlyingError=0x283368f90 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}) and URLS: [<AVPlayerItem: 0x283c1d4a0, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x2878f41c0, URL = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0CE62F51-77E0-4630-A3C4-1CE615ACCD26/tmp/uk.co.racelogic.Circuit-Tools-for-iOS-Inbox/VBOX0005_0001.mp4>>, <AVPlayerItem: 0x283c1d850, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x2878f5520, URL = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0CE62F51-77E0-4630-A3C4-1CE615ACCD26/tmp/uk.co.racelogic.Circuit-Tools-for-iOS-Inbox/VBOX0005_0002.mp4>>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as stated in error *"No such file or directory"* a file is absent. Regarding full path it stored inside temporary folder. Probably you imported these files via `UIDocumentPickerViewController` or similar component. You must copy provided file immediately (synchronously) in same code block where you get the URL to some local storage to avoid this situation.

Comment: yes, I am fetching it from UIDocumentPickerViewController. Is there any other way to access it directly and hold the instance of the temporary folder ? Copying the video files increases the application size and it leads to some other problems.

Comment: I don't know such way. If you use these files only part time then you could just delete them directly when you finish with them. But if you need them for a long time then you must have copy of them for all that time.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thanks mate.